# Convert decimal year to date in javascript in format mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: javascript, date

I figured out, after loooooooong research how to get my date into decimal years. Now, what I want to do is figure out is how to convert decimal years for example `2020.39123` into something like `11/24/2020`.

My preferred output format is `mm/dd/yyyy`. Not the long Date() output of `Wed Sep 02 2020 15:24 GMT-0300 (Time zone name)`.

My code so far is:

```
function myFunction() {
  var d = Date.parse("March 21, 2012");
  var minutes = 1000 * 60;
  var hours = minutes * 60;
  var days = hours * 24;
  var years = days * 365;
  var y = Math.round(d / years);

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the month of your date add before the string "0" and take the last 2 chars to get the month as 2-digit-value. Don't forget to add 1 for month because JS counts 0-11. Same formatting procedure for the date. Just add at the end the fullyear.

```js
function myFunction() {
  let d = new Date("March 21, 2012");
  let date = ('0' + (d.getMonth() +1)).slice(-2) + '/' + ('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + '/' + d.getFullYear();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = date;
}

myFunction();
```

```html
<div id='demo'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm in the OP is simplistic and doesn't account for days not being 24 hours long where daylight saving is observed. Also, not all years are 365 days long.

A more accurate algorithm would consider the actual number of milliseconds in a year and create a fraction from that. If the resolution is to be whole days, then the values should be rounded to the next whole day and 3 decimal places is sufficient. Otherwise, ECMAScript numbers don't have sufficient precision to preserve the value to millisecond accuracy and the decimal year won't be converted back to a date accurately (a variance of 1 ms can change the date to a different day).

E.g

```js
// Conversion of a Date to decimal year
// Resolution is to day only
function toDecimalYear(date) {
  // Copy date so don't affect original and set to start of day
  let d = new Date(date);
  d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  let year = d.getFullYear();
  let yearStart = new Date(year, 0, 1);
  let dayNum = Math.round((d - yearStart) / 8.64e7);
  let daysInYear = Math.round((new Date(year + 1, 0, 1) - yearStart) / 8.64e7);
  return +(year + dayNum / daysInYear).toFixed(3);
}

// Convert decimal year to Date
// Resolution is to nearest whole day
function fromDecimalYear(num) {
  let year = parseInt(num);
  let yearStart = new Date(year, 0, 1);
  let daysInYear = Math.round((new Date(year + 1, 0, 1) - yearStart) / 8.64e7);
  let dayNum = Math.round((num - year) * daysInYear)
  yearStart.setDate(1 + dayNum);
  return yearStart;
}

// Formatter
let f = date => date.toLocaleString('default',{
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'short',
  day: 'numeric',
  hour: '2-digit',
  hour12: false,
  minute: '2-digit',
  second: '2-digit',
  millisecond: 'numeric'
});

// OP example
console.log('2020.39123 => ' + f(fromDecimalYear(2020.39123)));

// Current date - set to start of day
let d = new Date();
d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
console.log(f(d) + ' = ' + toDecimalYear(d));

// Other test dates
[new Date(2012,  0,  1), // 01 Jan 2012 
 new Date(2012,  2, 12), // 12 Mar 2012
 new Date(2012, 11, 31)  // 31 Dec 2012
].forEach(date => {
  let dy = toDecimalYear(date);
  console.log(
      'Start date      : ' + f(date)
    + '\nAs decimal years: ' + dy
    + '\nBack to date    : ' + f(fromDecimalYear(dy))
  )
});
```

I think a better way to represent dates using years is to use year.dayNumber rather than fractional year. So 1 Jan 2020 is 2020.001, 1 Feb is 2020.032, etc. But then year month day is the same number of characters: 20200101, 20200201, etc.

Comment: I really love it! I just need decimal date to mm/dd/yyyy, but this really helped me!